# Getting error in parsing xml using SWXMLHash with Alamofire

Tags: swift, xml, parsing, alamofire, swxmlhash

I am using pods with Swift 4

```
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
```

When I am parsing XML with below code, getting the error:

```
Type 'XMLIndexer' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
```

Code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topgrossingapplications/limit=10/xml").response { response in
            debugPrint(response)

            guard let data = response.data else {
                return
            }

            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
            let nodes = xml["feed"]["entry"]
            for node in nodes {
                print(node["title"].text)
            }
        }
```

I am trying to access 'entry' tag list from above iTunes XML URL.
If there is any method to access and initialize the list of entries in class/struct, please help.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you need to add `all`:

```
Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topgrossingapplications/limit=10/xml").response { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        guard let data = response.data else {
            return
        }

        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
        let nodes = xml["feed"]["entry"]
        for node in nodes.all {
            print(node["title"]?.text)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is correct - when Swift 4 came out, there were breaking changes with the Sequence protocol so it was removed in favor of calling the all method.

Comment: I tried Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topgrossingapplications/limit=10/xml").response { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            
            guard let data = response.data else {
                return completion(.Failure("No weather item found"))
            }
            
            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
            let nodes = xml["feed"]["entry"]
            for node in nodes.all {
                print(node["title"].description)
            }
        }

Comment: 1- po xml
▿ 
  ▿ element : <SWXMLHash_Root_Element></SWXMLHash_Root_Element>

2- po xml["feed"]
▿ 
  ▿ xmlError : XML Element Error: Incorrect key ["feed"]
    - key : "feed"

3- po xml["feed"]["entry"]
▿ 
  ▿ xmlError : XML Element Error: Incorrect key ["entry"]
    - key : "entry"

Comment: Please extend your question. What you wrote in the comments is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi), which is based on the [Ono](https://github.com/mattt/Ono) framework, which had great support.

The following snippet will print the titles:

```
Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topgrossingapplications/limit=10/xml").responseString { response in
    guard let xml = try? XMLDocument(string: response.value ?? "") else {
        return
    }
    guard let feed = xml.root else {
        return
    }
    for entry in feed.children(tag: "entry") {
        let title = entry.firstChild(tag: "title")?.stringValue ?? ""
        print(title)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting some symbolic response when I am parsing my another xml after response from server like below:- XML: <urlset xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<items>
<title>
[Hindi] लखनऊ, वाराणसी, पटना, गया में सीज़न का सबसे कम न्यूनतम तापमान, दिन में मिलेगी राहत, रात में बढ़ेगी सर्दी
</title>
<articledate>05 January, 2018</articledate>
</items>
</urlset>

Comment: It has some other languages contents in hindi, tamil (like some indian languages) as mentioned in above comment. When I am trying to print it prints some symbolic characters like: - po entry.firstChild(tag: "title")?.stringValue
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "[Hindi] à¤²à¤à¤¨à¤, à¤µà¤¾à¤°à¤¾à¤£à¤¸à¥, à¤ªà¤à¤¨à¤¾, à¤à¤¯à¤¾ à¤®à¥à¤ à¤¸à¥à¥à¤¨ à¤à¤¾ à¤¸à¤¬à¤¸à¥ à¤à¤® à¤¨à¥à¤¯à¥à¤¨à¤¤à¤® à¤¤à¤¾à¤ªà¤®à¤¾à¤¨, à¤¦à¤¿à¤¨ à¤®à¥à¤ à¤®à¤¿à¤²à¥à¤à¥ à¤°à¤¾à¤¹à¤¤, à¤°à¤¾à¤¤ à¤®à¥à¤ à¤¬à¥à¥à¤à¥ à¤¸à¤°à¥à¤¦à¥"